# Render a component outside of the template in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to render a modal which is defined inside a template but this modal should be insert into the DOM outside of the template.

e.g.

my-list.hbs:

```
  <div>
    <button>Create item</button>
    {{#if creatingItem}}
      {{item-creation-modal}}
    {{/if}}
    <ul>
      {{#each items as |item|}}
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Basically what I want is to be able to render {{item-creation-modal}} outside of the DOM (typically at the end of the DOM) to be sure it's above everything.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is something along the lines of [ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole).

Comment: Yes Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.